# Start QuickTime and set camera to iPhone from command line

Tags: macos, video, iphone, applescript, camera

I'm attempting to start QuickTime from AppleScript and select the camera of my iPhone like I do from QuickTime. I can't seem to make it change the camera. 
The script I have now is:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
    tell newMovieRecording
        set camera to "iPhone"
        start
        delay 10 --(seconds)
        stop
    end tell
end tell
```

Of course the part of setting the camera to iPhone is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "select the camera of my iPhone"? Could you explain what you are trying to do, because (to me) that's unclear.

Comment: In Yosemite you can see your iPhone (ios 8+) screen in Quicktime, you just need to start a movie recording and switch the camera. I want to automate that exact behavior.

Comment: Pam: I got your script to work, but when I saved it as an App, it will only start recording the regular webcam, unfortunately.